# Cauchy's Theorem for a continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm not sure where to begin a mathematical proof of this theorem,  i know that this theorem would be false if the function f was holomorphic instead of continuous, so would that also mean this statement is false?

Comment: I think you mean the statement is **true** for holomorphic $f$.  Hint: try an $f$ that is $0$ over most of the contour and nonzero on a small piece of it.

Comment: As Robert said, This statement is supposed to make you think about what is $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ exactly, and how strong is the condition $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$ for every closed contour $\gamma$

Answer (score 0):

If the domain $U$ were simply connected and the function holomorphic instead of continuous on $U$, then indeed that integral would be zero (Cauchy).  So your reasoning does not demonstrate that the statement is false.

Now consider another  cases that fails to  demonstrate the statement is false:

- $U = z: |z| > 2$ and $f(z) = 5+\frac1z$, and let the contour $\gamma$ be the circle $|z|=3$.  Then $f(z)$ is continuous (in fact holomorphic) on $U$, and image of $\gamma$  always has absolute value at least $13/3$ so it lies in $U$, and the integral around $gamma$ is non-zero.  However, the interior of $\gamma$ is not completely in $U$, so this is not a probabative example.

BUt now consider $U = z: |z| > 2$, and $f(z) = |z|$,  and let the contour $\gamma$ be the circle $|z|=1$.  Then the immage of $f(z)$ lies in $U$, the interior of $\gamma$ lies in $U$, and the integral has value $2\pi\neq 0$.  That means the statement is false.

Comment: You don't need $U$ to be simply connected for $f$ holomorphic in the set up the OP describes.

Comment: but then surely for your last example the interior and image don't lie in U? As $U=z:|z|\gt2$ which is the area outside of a circle radius 2 and gamma is not in that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about $f(z) = \bar z$ integrated along $\gamma (t) = a + re^{it},$ assuming $\overline {D(a,r)} \subset U.$

Comment: so the statement is true? I'm having trouble implementing a proof from your hint, could you explain please?

Comment: Did you calculate the integral? It's a simple calculation.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do the contour integral when you have $f(z)=\z overline$ and with $\gamma=a+re^(it)$ as there are only letters, maybe i'm just missing something.

Comment: The integral in question is $\int_0^{2\pi} \overline {a + re^{it}} \cdot ire^{it}\, dt.$

Comment: would it be $2\pi ir^2$

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: So if r is non zero then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz\neq0$?

Comment: You need to be able to answer questions like that on your own.

Comment: Well clearly it is correct but i'm not sure how you can link in to a mathematical proof of the statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what your confusion is. You've seen that the continuous function $\bar z$ does not give $0$ for the integral.